# fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation in wine

Tags: linux, terminal, wine

I am trying to launch setup to install an app with wine.

Launching it without the terminal does nothing, however launching it in the terminal with the command `wine foosetup.exe` it gives the error `fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0` and returns to the terminal prompt with `foo@computer_name:~/Downloads$`

Does anyone know how to fix this? This is really frustrating as its happened to all the .exe files I tried to install with wine.

I have the latest version of wine (1.7) and the Linux OS is Elementary OS which runs wine completely fine when installing .NET 4.0 to run the setup for `foosetup.exe`